# Would like to plot mean of grouped data and add confidence limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data for which I need to calculate and plot the mean and a 95% confidence limits, but I don't know where I'm going wrong with my code.  The data is grouped by year and I thought about using stat_smooth() to draw a confidence interval region, but I just can't get it off the ground.  If I try I get an error:

> Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour,
>   size and linetype must be constant over the line

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr) 
dat <- data.frame(cbind(rep(1:10,10),rnorm(100,600,sd=100),rnorm(100,400,sd=50),rnorm(100,700,sd=100)))
colnames(dat) <- c("year","S4","S5","S6")

    df<-data.frame(dat)
    ggplot(df)+
      geom_line(aes(x=year, y=mean(df$S4),colour=year)) +
      geom_line(aes(x=year, y=quantile(df$S4,0.95),colour=year),linetype="dotted") +
      geom_line(aes(x=year, y=quantile(df$S4,0.05),colour=year),linetype="dotted")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you use `stat_summary`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = S4)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, linetype = "solid") +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", fun.data= mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=.1)
```

**Plot**

[image: plot with mean and 95% CI]

**Edit:**

With multiple variables/lines, would recommend putting data in "long" format first with `pivot_longer`, then plot. Perhaps could use different colors for different variables.

```
df <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(S4, S5, S6), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "line", fun = mean, linetype = "solid") +
  stat_summary(geom = "ribbon", fun.data= mean_cl_normal, fun.args = list(conf.int=0.95), alpha=.1)
```

Comment: Would I have to create an entirely  new plot if I had several variables?  Not sure why I get the error:  Error: (converted from warning) Ignoring unknown parameters: fun

Comment: If you'd like, edit your question with what your data would look like with 2-3 variables that you'd like to plot. Would you want multiple lines with multiple confidence intervals on the same plot? Feel free to describe further.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Yes, I'm looking for multiple lines with CLs on the same plot.  I tried to run your example but got an error:  Error: (converted from warning) Ignoring unknown parameters: fun

Comment: Can you join me on chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209638/room-for-ben-and-angus